Wifi randomly disconnects after some time & Never come back unless system restarted | Fedora 40
I recently purchased a new laptop and I am having a wifi disconnectivity issue in my lonovo machine (ThinkBook 16 G6 ABP with AMD processor). The wifi randomly disconnects after some time and never come back unless system restarted. I initially installed Ubuntu 24 on my new machine but It was creating issues more frequently then I moved to Fedora recently (the frequency of issue is less than Ubuntu).
I have tried many solutions found on stackoverflow and Ubuntu & Fedora forums but none of them are working for me.
What I tried before:

Re-build kernel with custom configurations (my friend suggested)
Disabled Wifi power saving (not working for me, but working for others on the forums)
Changed router's wireless configurations (not worked)

Related information

Error found in dmesg
Error: mac init fail, ret:-110

Check out logs: dmesg logs link

output from lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be



output from sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: f4:a8:0d:b3:6e:41
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.11-300.fc40.x86_64 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:56 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd604000-fd604fff memory:fd600000-fd603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 12:40:ae:6c:16:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.8.11-300.fc40.x86_64 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.33.49 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:81 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd500000-fd5fffff


Output from uname -a:
Linux fedora 6.8.11-300.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 27 14:53:33 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux


System Propeties as per neofetch:
             .',;::::;,'.                khaleel-unix@fedora 
         .';:cccccccccccc:;,.            ------------------- 
      .;cccccccccccccccccccccc;.         OS: Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
    .:cccccccccccccccccccccccccc:.       Host: 21KK ThinkBook 16 G6 ABP 
  .;ccccccccccccc;.:dddl:.;ccccccc;.     Kernel: 6.8.11-300.fc40.x86_64 
 .:ccccccccccccc;OWMKOOXMWd;ccccccc:.    Uptime: 29 mins 
.:ccccccccccccc;KMMc;cc;xMMc:ccccccc:.   Packages: 2056 (rpm), 7 (snap) 
,cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cc;;WW::cccccccc,   Shell: bash 5.2.26 
:cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:ccccccc;oxOOOo;MMM0OOk.;cccccccccccc:   DE: GNOME 46.2 
cccccc:0MMKxdd:;MMMkddc.;cccccccccccc;   WM: Mutter 
ccccc:XM0';cccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc'   WM Theme: Adwaita 
ccccc;MMo;ccccc;MMW.;ccccccccccccccc;    Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
ccccc;0MNc.ccc.xMMd:ccccccccccccccc;     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
cccccc;dNMWXXXWM0::cccccccccccccc:,      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
cccccccc;.:odl:.;cccccccccccccc:,.       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 7530U with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 4.546GHz 
:cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc:'.         GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Barcelo 
.:cccccccccccccccccccccc:;,..            Memory: 3300MiB / 62120MiB 



